# How can I catch a database error in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a unique constraint on a database field. When a duplicate is submitted I'd like to avoid sending a 500 response. How can I catch this error in DRF and return a 4XX response instead?

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/ try this may helpful for you

Answer (score 5):

I knew I needed to put a try/except block around something, but I didn't know what. I looked at the DRF code, and I saw that generics.ListCreateAPIView has a method called **create**. I wrote a new function inside my class called the parent **create** which has the same signature as the one I inherited, which called **create**, and I put the try/except around this function.

In the end it looks like this:

```
class MyModelList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModel.objects.all()
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(MyModelList, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except IntegrityError:
            raise CustomUniqueException
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: While this method works, if you find yourself repeating it often you'd be better served by @Cartucho's answer about using a custom exception handler.

Answer (score 5):

If you want this **only for this view** override `handle_exception`:

```
class MyAPIView(APIView):
  ...

  def handle_exception(self, exc):
      """
      Handle any exception that occurs, by returning an appropriate
      response,or re-raising the error.
      """
      ...
```

To handle it for **all views**, you can define a global exception handler, see here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions